# converting mysql statement to sql server with indexes

Tags: mysql, sql-server, indexing

I've been working on this for a few hours and am at a bind. Please help me if you can, i'd appreciate it...

Im trying to convert a series of mysql statements to sql server 2008 express, for a small wordpress database migration project. Im no pro in MS SQL databases...

I've gotten the majority of the statement converted, but need help with how to handle the table indexes statement near the bottom of the mySQL statement. How do i convert those to SQL Server compatible statements?:

mySQL statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_pollsip`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_pollsip` (
  `pollip_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pollip_qid` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pollip_aid` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pollip_ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pollip_host` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pollip_timestamp` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `pollip_user` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `pollip_userid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pollip_id`),
  KEY `pollip_ip` (`pollip_id`),
  KEY `pollip_qid` (`pollip_qid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table .wp_pollsip: ~5 rows (approximately)
DELETE FROM `wp_pollsip`;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_pollsip` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `wp_pollsip` (`pollip_id`, `pollip_qid`, `pollip_aid`, `pollip_ip`, `pollip_host`, `pollip_timestamp`, `pollip_user`, `pollip_userid`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1344836172', 'admin', 1),
(2, '2', '6', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1344836700', 'admin', 1),
(3, '3', '9', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1344963379', 'Guest', 0),
(4, '4', '12', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1345136711', 'admin', 1),
(5, '4', '14', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1345171584', 'Guest', 0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_pollsip` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

MS SQL, so far:

```
-- Dumping structure for table .wp_pollsip
IF OBJECT_ID('wp_pollsip','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE wp_pollsip;
CREATE TABLE wp_pollsip (
  pollip_id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  pollip_qid varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_aid varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_ip varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_host varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_timestamp varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  pollip_user char(256) NOT NULL,
  pollip_userid int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  --PRIMARY KEY (pollip_id),
  --KEY pollip_ip (pollip_id),
  --KEY pollip_qid (pollip_qid)
);

-- Dumping data for table .wp_pollsip: ~5 rows (approximately)
DELETE FROM wp_pollsip;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE wp_pollsip DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO wp_pollsip (pollip_qid, pollip_aid, pollip_ip, pollip_host, pollip_timestamp, pollip_user, pollip_userid) VALUES
('1', '1', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1344836172', 'admin', 1),
('2', '6', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1344836700', 'admin', 1),
('3', '9', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1344963379', 'Guest', 0),
('4', '12', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1345136711', 'admin', 1),
('4', '14', '11.11.11.11', 'isp-here', '1345171584', 'Guest', 0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE wp_pollsip ENABLE KEYS */;
```

I hope this makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSSQL, you typically create the indexes explicitly, except for the primary key:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('wp_pollsip','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE wp_pollsip;

CREATE TABLE wp_pollsip (
  pollip_id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY primary key,
  pollip_qid varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_aid varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  pollip_ip varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_host varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  pollip_timestamp varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  pollip_user char(256) NOT NULL,
  pollip_userid int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);

create index idx_wp_pollsip_gid on wp_pollsip(pollip_gid);
```

You don't need to create an index on pollip_id, because it is declared as the primary key.

Comment: Thanks, i think that worked.

I think you may have meant "pollip_qid" as opposed to "pollip_gid".  Change the g to q.

create index idx_wp_pollsip_gid on wp_pollsip(pollip_gid);